# Vagrant ssh X11 forwarding an android emulator

Tags: ssh, xorg, pulseaudio, android, vagrant

I've prepared an Android development environment using apache cordova inside a vagrant box with Ubuntu 16.04 by following mainly this guide except using the latest android sdk tools (`sdkmanager` & `avdmanager`).

I enabled ssh X11 forwarding by adding the following in the Vagrantfile:

```
config.ssh.forward_agent = true 
config.ssh.forward_x11 = true
```

but when I'm trying to run the Android emulator with `cordova emulate android`, a new window is opened for a while but then it gets stuck (stops loading) and I'm gettin' back the following X11 error:

```
No emulator specified, defaulting to Android-27
Waiting for emulator to start...
emulator: Requested console port 5584: Inferring adb port 5585.
emulator: WARNING: encryption is off
pulseaudio: pa_context_connect() failed
pulseaudio: Reason: Connection refused
pulseaudio: Failed to initialize PA contextaudio: Could not init `pa' audio driver
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  130 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  1 (X_ShmAttach)
  Serial number of failed request:  14
  Current serial number in output stream:  15
```

Any idea on how to approach solving this? I looked for the existence of `/var/log/<Xorg.log>` but couldn't find one.

**EDIT:** I run `journalctl -f` in anotherr window and before the crash, it logged down these:

```
Dec 13 17:20:35 cordova pulseaudio[2702]: [pulseaudio] server-lookup.c: Unable to contact D-Bus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: /usr/bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally without any error message
Dec 13 17:20:35 cordova pulseaudio[2702]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Unable to contact D-Bus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: /usr/bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally without any error message
```